# How do I get the alert message to display at the same time as the change in background color of the page?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JavaScript so pardon me if my question is not phrased appropriately. I would like to display the alert message once the loop is ended simultaneously with the change in the background color of the document.

This is my code:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Help Needed!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var target;
        var guess_input_text;
        var guess_input;
        var finished = false;
        var guesses = 0;
        var color = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Chocolate", "Crimson", "Gold", "Green", "Indigo", "Lavendar", "Lime", "Orange"];
        function do_game() {
            var random_number = (Math.random() * 11) + 1;
            var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number);
            target = color[random_number_integer-1];
            alert(target);

            while (!finished) {
                guess_input_text = prompt("Please enter a color from \n\n" + color.join(", ") + "\n\n" + "What is the color?");
                guesses += 1;
                finished = check_guess();
            }

            if (finished = true) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = target;
                alert("You got it! The color was " + target + ".\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to get the color!")
            }

        function check_guess() {
            if (guess_input_text.toUpperCase() > target.toUpperCase()) {
                alert("The chosen color is alphabetically higher than the actual color. \n\n" + "Please try again!");
                return false;
            }
            if (guess_input_text.toUpperCase() < target.toUpperCase()) {
                alert("The chosen color is alphabetically lower than the actual color. \n\n" + "Please try again!");
                return false;
            }
            if (guess_input_text.toUpperCase() != target.toUpperCase()) {
                alert("Your answer is not in the selection provided! \n\n" + "Please try again!");
                return false;
            }
            if (guess_input_text.toUpperCase() == target.toUpperCase()) 
                return true;
            }           
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="do_game()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was under the assumption you'd wish to know how to change the backgroundcolor, but doesn't this code do that already?

Comment: You're making an assignment in your if statement, not equaility check `if (finished = true)`. Also, when program leaves the while loop, there is no need for checking if variable `finished` is equals to true, because otherwise your loop will not end.

Comment: @Roberrrt, I was hoping to get it to display at the same time the alert message is shown. However, the background color currently only shows after I click ok on the alert message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of refactoring you could make your game accept a lot more simply by using some parameters in the game.

I only kept your colors variable in the global scope and for the rest, the questions and inputs are given as parameters.

It can make it a lot easier when later you might want to choose cake flavors or anything like that. For your randomization, you don't need to add 1 as a Javascript array starts from 0, and you can use `parseInt` instead of `Math.floor`

Also, to check if the data you gave in is inside your dataset, you would have to either join the array and check if it contains your guess, or you iterate it in a way (the for loop in the check_guess function)

```js
'use strict';
var colors = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Chocolate", "Crimson", "Gold", "Green", "Indigo", "Lavendar", "Lime", "Orange"];

function do_game(possibleSolutions, title) {
  // you don't need to add one (arrays start from 0
  var random_number = parseInt((Math.random() * possibleSolutions.length)),
    solution = possibleSolutions[random_number],
    guesses = 0, finished;
  console.log(solution);
  while (!finished) {
    finished = check_guess(prompt("Please enter a " + title + " from \n\n" + possibleSolutions.join(", ") + "\n\n" + "What is the " + title + "?"), random_number, possibleSolutions);
    guesses += 1;
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = solution;
  setTimeout(function( title, solution ) {
    alert("You got it! The " + title + " was " + solution + ".\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to get the " + title + "!", title);
  }.bind(null, title, solution), 0);
}

function check_guess(guess, option, colors, title) {
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (guess.toUpperCase() === colors[i].toUpperCase()) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    alert("The " + title + " you suggested is not in the given range!");
    return false;
  }

  if (guess.toUpperCase() > colors[option].toUpperCase()) {
    alert("The chosen " + title + " is alphabetically higher than the actual " + title + ". \n\n" + "Please try again!");
    return false;
  }

  if (guess.toUpperCase() < colors[option].toUpperCase()) {
    alert("The chosen " + title + " is alphabetically lower than the actual " + title + ". \n\n" + "Please try again!");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

do_game( colors, 'color');
```

Comment: Thanks Icepickle! I replied in the prior comment but didn't realised that the answer is already here. New to JavaScript so really appreciate the help :)

Comment: @ShaneLow I'm happy I could help. The reason why your background-color wasn't set when you saw the alert is because of the way javascript handles an alert. An alert is a blocking code, it will stop the execution of your method until the alert is closed. As the rendering of any changes you make to the DOM in your code won't happen until it exists the function, and as the alert is stopping you from leaving the function, the background won't be changed. The setTimeout delays the showing of the alert so that the browser first processes your changes, and then shows the alert

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `+1` assignment from your `var random_number` statement and instead of 11 put the actual elements of your array just like,

`var random_number = (Math.random() * 10);`

**Here is the working code,**

```
    var target;
    var guess_input_text;
    var guess_input;
    var finished = false;
    var guesses = 0;
    var color = ["Aqua", "Blue", "Chocolate", "Crimson", "Gold", "Green", "Indigo", "Lavendar", "Lime", "Orange"];
    function do_game() {
        var random_number = (Math.random() * 10);
        var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number);
        target = color[random_number_integer-1];
        alert(target);

        while (!finished) {
            guess_input_text = prompt("Please enter a color from \n\n" + color.join(", ") + "\n\n" + "What is the color?");
            guesses += 1;
            finished = check_guess();
        }

        if (finished = true) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = target;
            alert("You got it! The color was " + target + ".\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to get the color!")
        }

    function check_guess() {
        if (guess_input_text.toUpperCase() > target.toUpperCase()) {
            alert("The chosen color is alphabetically higher than the actual color. \n\n" + "Please try again!");
            return false;
        }
        if (guess_input_text.toUpperCase() < target.toUpperCase()) {
            alert("The chosen color is alphabetically lower than the actual color. \n\n" + "Please try again!");
            return false;
        }
        if (guess_input_text.toUpperCase() != target.toUpperCase()) {
            alert("Your answer is not in the selection provided! \n\n" + "Please try again!");
            return false;
        }
        if (guess_input_text.toUpperCase() == target.toUpperCase()) 
            return true;
        }           
    }
```

**Working fiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/pL1bxc3x/3/

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are leaving the `finished = true` assignment after the while?

Comment: @Icepickle I had to rectify only the target fetching statement although your  point make sense though.

Comment: but also that one could be better, instead of decreasing it by 2, you can just remove the + 1 when picking the random nr...

Comment: @Icepickle Well, I had tried that too, it was actually displaying the same error.

Comment: Maybe because the array only has 10 elements, in my version i just took the array.length instead of a hard coded value

Comment: I did, I think I stated enough reasons above, and also gave you time to do the edits. You could make your suggestion so much better, you left in obvious errors and you altered the symptom, but not the cause.

Comment: @Icepickle Sorry mate, I was trying to answer another SO thread, I have updated the answer as requred. Thanks for the heads up! :-)

Comment: I reverted the down vote however (as you removed the "biggest" error), however I think the only thing you should put in is the correction to the random number and nothing else. The assignment issue with his if is not a "big" thing in this case (since it will always be true at that time), but it should be made clear to the OP, the check_guess will not return the expected when I type in banana (the check if it is part of the solution space is just not correct (will also never be hit, as the smaller than and greater than will already cancel it out...)). As I said, much to improve in that code

Comment: Hi Ice, what you said makes a lot of sense. Could I know how to reach the last "if" conclusion when they don't select anything in the array? Thanks!